# Problem installing the R package 'RcppEigen' on Mac OS X

Tags: r, rcpp

I tried to install the R package "RcppEigen" I get an error message. I'm not exactly sure how to problem solve the warning it produces. The warning message seems to relate to "../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
        #pragma clang diagnostic pop" 
Thank you!! Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    > install.packages("RcppEigen")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
             binary    source needs_compilation
RcppEigen 0.3.3.3.1 0.3.3.5.0              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘RcppEigen’

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1595k  100 159 0    05k    0     0  7445k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 7455k
* installing *source* package ‘RcppEigen’ ...
** package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
In file included from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Core:535:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:2:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/LU:47:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:3:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Cholesky:12:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Jacobi:29:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:3:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Cholesky:43:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:4:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/QR:17:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Householder:27:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:5:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/SVD:48:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:6:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Geometry:58:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:26:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/SparseCore:66:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:27:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/OrderingMethods:71:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:29:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/SparseCholesky:43:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:32:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/SparseQR:35:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:33:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers:46:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:32:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/CholmodSupport:45:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:35:
In file included from ../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/KroneckerProduct:34:
../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:39:
In file included from ../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/Polynomials:135:
../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:40:
In file included from ../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra:51:
../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
17 warnings generated.
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Core:535:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:2:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/LU:47:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:3:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Cholesky:12:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Jacobi:29:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:3:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Cholesky:43:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:4:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/QR:17:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Householder:27:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:5:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/SVD:48:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:6:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Geometry:58:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:7:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Eigenvalues:58:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:26:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/SparseCore:66:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:27:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/OrderingMethods:71:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:29:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/SparseCholesky:43:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:32:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/SparseQR:35:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:31:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Sparse:33:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers:46:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:32:
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/CholmodSupport:45:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:35:
In file included from ../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/KroneckerProduct:34:
../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:39:
In file included from ../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/Polynomials:135:
../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from fastLm.cpp:23:
In file included from ./fastLm.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:40:
In file included from ../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra:51:
../inst/include/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
17 warnings generated.
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o RcppEigen.so RcppEigen.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o init.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RcppEigen.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppEigen’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/9_/f0jqcgq13n97m79xtsl57kn40000gn/T/RtmpSiuVuo/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: The warnings are just that, warnings that one would normally suppress, but CRAN policy does not allow that on a package level. The error about missing gfortran is the culprit here. Please follow http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/ to setup the compiler toolchain.